# How to send a dm to a user using commands

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm scripting a bot to dm a certain user a message that I write for example I will do:

```
!dm @user Hi!
```

And the bot will send that user the dm saying only Hi!

It doesn't let me, can someone please check my code?

```
if(command === "dm") {
      let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
      if(!member)
          return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
      let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
      mentionedUser.send(`${reason}`);

}
```

Updated code:

```
  if(command === "dm") {
  let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
  if(!member)
      return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");

  let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason)
        return message.reply("Please write a message.");
  member.dmChannel.send(`${reason}`);
  message.reply(`${member.user.tag} received a message( ${reason} ) sent by:${message.author.tag}`);

  }
```

Now I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: version: 10.16.3

Answer (score 0):

You can DM the user by fetching the user's DM first,

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
//...
member.dmChannel.send("")
```

Alternatively, you can use [`createDM()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) instead.

Comment: I get this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: mention is not defined`

Comment: @zap Did you change anything else? Also, you need to mention a user for it to work. Your error does not seem to belong to any part of my written code.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer pertains **only** to versions 11 and later.*

---

There's no need to access the client's DM channel with the user (which needs to be instantiated first anyway). Simply use the [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) or [`GuildMember.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) method.

```js
member.send(reason)
  .catch(console.error);
```